# Procmail split mailing list answer

Tags: email, procmail

The common ethicete about mailing lists is to answer to a human, and CC the mailing list, like this:

```
To: help-volounter@dev.full
Cc: some-program@mailing-list.com
Subject: Re: Describtion of the problem
```

Problem is that I get two copies of such email(it's expected). I would like to `procmail` one copy to mailing list mbox, and another to inbox mbox. Is it simple way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely trivial, but there are some building blocks you may find useful.

You can detect whether you have already received a message by keeping a cache of seen message-id:s.  This is a standard technique described in the [`procmailex` man page](http://www.themanualpage.org/man/man5/procmailex.5.php) in more detail.  I would propose to use the same technique to decide where to file an incoming message; if it has not been seen before, deliver to your inbox; otherwise, file to the list's folder.

The locking becomes somewhat more complex because you need to obtain the lock file before entering the `formail -D` recipe.  This can be done by using the `LOCKFILE` special variable.

```
# Is this message addressed both to yourself and to the list?
:0
* ^TO_you@example\.net\>
* ^TO_mailing-list@elsewhere\.example\.org\>
{
    # Select regular inbox as default target for this message
    dest=$DEFAULT

    # Lock msgid.lock for exclusive access to msgid.cache
    LOCKFILE=msgid.lock

    # If message-id is already cached, override $dest
    :0
    * H ? formail -D 8192 msgid.cache
    { dest=listbox/ }

    # Release lock
    LOCKFILE=

    # Deliver to $dest
    :0
    $dest
}
```

This is not 100% foolproof.  If you get a `Bcc:`, for example, your own address will not be in the headers, and so `^TO_` *yourself* will not match.